# Why does this boolean expression return false when each term is true?

Tags: io, f#, f#-interactive

```ml
> (Console.Read() = (int 'd'));;
d
val it: bool = true

> (Console.Read() = (int 'd')) && (Console.Read() = (int 'o'));;
val it: bool = false
```

It seems to terminate without calling Read, how does the compiler know to make the expression false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful with Read(), it also picks up the line termination character(s). You can see this if you start a clean F# interactive session and do the following:

```
> Console.Read();;
d
val it : int = 100

> Console.Read();;
val it : int = 13

> Console.Read();;
val it : int = 10
```

Obviously I did this on Windows, since the line termination was \r\n.

You should probably use ReadKey() (which you can't use in an FSI session) or ReadLine(). For example,

```
> Console.ReadLine() = "do";;
do
val it : bool = true

>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I am interested in doing parsing [of text files], so I did not think ReadKey was the right method. Also, the console did not wait for input, what do you think it read?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow your question. Also, if you're parsing text files, you would want to  use something like File.ReadLines(),

Comment: In the first interactive session, you can see the 'd' I entered. In the second there is none. This seems to be an issue with the interative session, since my code worked in a compiled session.

Comment: Read() blocks until you press <Enter>. Then each call will give you one character until there is no input anymore, at which point it blocks again. So you entered 'd'. The first Read() gave you 100, and the next two calls returned 13 and 10 (which you compared to 100 and 111). Another call to Read() would then block again, waiting for new input.